# Setting stack size with GCC 4.6.2 C++ Qt, MinGW, Vista

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, windows-vista, stack-size

I want to increase the stack size of my program because I have a complex recursive algorithm it would be a REAL pain to rewrite iteratively.

I am using GCC C++ 4.6.2. MinGw, building with a Qt .pro file (I'm using Qt for the GUI front end), on Vista.

Advice on this website is to use:-

```
gcc -Wl,--stack,4194304
```

and to send this to the g++ link phase with:-

```
LIB += -Wl,--stack,4194304
```

but the linker errors with:-

> g++: error: unrecognized option '--stack,4194304'

I have tried sending the options to the compile phase with QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += but g++ still barfs.

The only option that does not barf is -fno-stack-limit from the GCC documentation (.pdf 4.5.0, p.260), but my stack still overflows. The other options mentioned in that para. barf.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wl,--stack,4194304` to your .pro file.

Comment: Thanks. I had a space between -Wl and --stack, which is why G++ barfed (Doh!). However, I have found the options should be on the link phase, they are ignored by the compile phase. Thus it should be:- LIB += -Wl,--stack,4194304 in the Ot qmake .pro file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ulimit -s STACK_SIZE
```